# R Importing from sqlite database into dataframe don't find a variable that is in the database

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

My problem with R is that when I try to import from a database using Dplyr it says that "object XXX not found" but the same function was working until now!

this is my complete code.

```
connection <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="../dataset/ontime.sqlite3")

from_db <- function(sql){
dbGetQuery(ontime, sql)
}

ontime <- tbl(connection, "ontime")

number_of_flights <- ontime %>%
  filter(Cancelled == 0) %>%
  select(Year, TailNum, Cancelled) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise(NumberOfFlights = n_distinct(TailNum)) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

and it returns me:

Error in n_distinct_multi(list(...), na.rm) : object "TailNum" not found.

this same function worked until half an hour ago, and I have modified nothing!

Could you please help me understand what is happening here?

thanks in advance

Comment: What does `colnames(ontime)` return?

Comment: [1] "Year"              "Month"             "DayofMonth"        "DayOfWeek"         "DepTime"           "CRSDepTime"   [7] "ArrTime"           "CRSArrTime"        "UniqueCarrier"     "FlightNum"         "TailNum"           "ActualElapsedTime"
[13] "CRSElapsedTime"    "AirTime"           "ArrDelay"          "DepDelay"          "Origin"            "Dest"             
[19] "Distance"          "TaxiIn"            "TaxiOut"           "Cancelled"         "CancellationCode"  "Diverted"         
[25] "CarrierDelay"      "WeatherDelay"      "NASDelay"          "SecurityDelay"     "LateAircraftDelay"

Comment: And you get the same error when you start a new R session and run just this code?

Comment: Yes, I've also rebooted the PC. I'm using Rstudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

I found that this error shows up after loading the library `Rmisc`, so maybe something between this library and `dplyr` is in conflict.